# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a website but I encounter a problem when I press button "Load More" after 3 times. It gives me an error of "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"...I guess something wrong with slice and map function!
P.S. I tried to call "id" to other component but in vain!

```
class PostsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      visible: 3,
      error: false
    };

    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return {visible: prev.visible + 3};
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        posts: res
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({
        error: true
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.section}>
        <h2 className={classes.title}>Latest news</h2>
        <div>
          <GridContainer>
            {
              this.state.posts.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((post, i) => {
               return (
                  <PostCard key={i}
                  id={posts[i].id}
                  date={posts[i].date} 
                  fbimg={posts[i].fbimg} 
                  description={posts[i].description} 
                  fbpost={posts[i].fbpost}
                  />
                );
              })
            } 
          </GridContainer> 
           <GridContainer>
            <GridItem>
            {this.state.visible < this.state.posts.length &&
              <Button 
                color="info"
                onClick={this.loadMore} 
              >
              Load more
              </Button>
            }
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: It's basically a typo, `posts` instead of `this.state.posts`. (But again, don't do that, use `post`.)

Comment: Once again, the horror of automatic DOM globals hits us (probably). Apparently you have an `id="posts"` element somewhere, so `posts` in your `map` callback finds that rather than not finding anything (which would have given you a clearer error). :-|

Comment: @T.J. Crowder...Yes you are right! It was a typo(```posts``` instead of ```this.state.posts```)....Thank you!!! It worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts` is not defined inside your render function.  Did you mean `this.state.posts`?

Also, there's no need to use the index to access posts when you already have the single `post` available from your `map` function.  So change `posts[i].id` to `post.id`.

Comment: Or even better, just `post` rather than `posts[i]`.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder ...I changed the code as you suggested and is working fine!!!